# How can I partition a vector to n different parts in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector `i` as follows:

```
i = 
[1627
1628
1629
1630
1631
1632
1633
1634
1635
1636
1637
1638
1639
1640
1641
1642
1643
1644
1645
10585
10586
10587
10588
10589
10590
10591
10592
10593
10594
10595
10596
10597
10598
10599
10600
10601
10602
10603]
```

I'd like to break it to two vectors as follows:

```
v1 = 
[1627
1628
1629
1630
1631
1632
1633
1634
1635
1636
1637
1638
1639
1640
1641
1642
1643
1644
1645]
```

and

```
v2 =
[10585
10586
10587
10588
10589
10590
10591
10592
10593
10594
10595
10596
10597
10598
10599
10600
10601
10602
10603]
```

So far, I've used the unique function as follows:

```
[b,m,n] = unique(diff(i));
```

Where `m` gives me the indices for the critical points as follows:

```
m = sort(m)+1;

m =
[20
38]
```

In conjunction with the m values this is the snippet I use to MANUALLY accomplish my goal:

```
v1 = i(1:m(1)-1)

v2 = i(m(1):m(2))
```

So, in summary, I'd like to have n different vectors, from one large one, based on n different values returned from unique in a more efficient and straightforward way. Apologies for the extra long post.

Comment: Personally I don't see a problem with this approach.  Divakar and Luis Mendo: Any advice?

Comment: If you are looking to separate into two parts, this looks efficient already.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the splitting criterion is. For example, if the last entry of `i` was `10605` instead of `10603`, what would the intended result be?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I guess it would be three vectors, where the last one would only be `10605`. Criterion: `diff(a)~=1`, don't you think?

Comment: @RoberP The OP uses `unique(diff(..))`. That's why I don't see it clear what the criterion is

Comment: The goal is to be able to capture the difference between successive elements in the i array greater than 1. So for example if after 10603 it was 10605, a third vector would be required with 10605 as the first element. The solution Robert P provided seems to solve the problem at first glance. I will have to further test it for full evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this that's independent of the number of elements in each set, and the number of sets is:

```
a = [1:4, 10:14, 45:47];
ind = [0 find(diff([a, inf])~=1)];
b = arrayfun(@(n) a(ind(n)+1:ind(n+1)), 1:numel(ind)-1, 'UniformOutput', 0);

b{:}
ans =
     1     2     3     4

ans =
    10    11    12    13    14

ans =
    45    46    47
```

Now `b{1} = [1 2 3 4]`, `b{2} = [10 11 12 13 14]` and `b{3} = [45 46 47]`.

This [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) line is in this case equivalent to:

```
for n = 1:numel(ind)-1
   b{n} = a(ind(n)+1 : ind(n+1));
end
```

Now it's possible to do the following: However, I will advice you to keep it as cells the way it is

```
v1 = b{1};
v2 = b{2};
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've explained the question better (in the comments): [Stewie Griffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23713600/2586922) does what you want. Or you can avoid `arrayfun` and do it in one line:

```
v = mat2cell(i, diff([0 find(diff(i)>1).' numel(i)]));
```

Comment: @StewieGriffin Will your change of name be definitive? I'm asking to update my reference above to your answer

Comment: @LuisMendo, yes, it'll be permanent. I have realized that Stewie does more awesome stuff than Robert, so I was hoping to impersonate him, and see what my new and hopefully improved life would become. =P Also, I now have an awesome British voice! I decided to keep the avatar unchanged, in order to keep some of my SO-identity (if I have any) =) Thanks for caring to change the reference Luis!

Comment: @StewieGriffin The avatar did help actually. Otherwise I might not have known it was you. Reference changed!

Answer (score 0):

The n vectors seem to have the same length. That should do the job (not tested)

```
n_elem_per_vector = find(diff(i) > 1, 1);
n_vector = numel(i) / n_elem_per_vector;
reshaped_i = reshape(i, n_elem_per_vector, n_vector);
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This problem was discussed on Loren's Art of MATLAB Blog [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/11/14/partitioning-a-vector/) back in 2012.

One of the commenters (Ed) provided an excellent solution:

```
out = mat2cell(a,1,accumarray(1+cumsum([0,diff(a)~=1])',ones(size(a))'));
```